# Get all Discussion board URL using PowerShell SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, discussion-board

How to retrieve the URL of all Discussion Board in a web application using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through each site collection and web site to find a matching list.

This could take a while, and you will need appropraite permissions (e.g. a web application policy).

```
$discussionLibraryTemplateId = 108
# http://mirusp2010.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/list-template-id.html

# Find all site collections for a web app.
$sites = Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://tugboatTours.com

foreach($site in $sites)
{
    // Iterate through each web site.
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        foreach($list in $web.Lists)
        {
            if ( (-not $list.Hidden) -and $list.BaseTemplate -eq $discussionLibraryTemplateId)
            {
                write-output $list.Name $list.Url
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The C# (CSOM) version of this is here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50907/programmatically-find-lists-by-template-id